# Getting an array from another class objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray

I have xml file and I raed all information in xml file and store in array,

here is my starDidElement file for storing in array:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Presentation"]) {
    NSLog(@"user element found – create a new instance of User class...");
    app.presentationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    thePresentation = [[Presentation alloc] init];
    thePresentation.pLabel = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"label"];
    NSLog(@"PLabel: %@", thePresentation.pLabel);

}else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"slides"]) {
    NSLog(@"Slides");

    thePresentation.slides = [NSMutableArray array];
```

and in my header I have

```
   Presentation thePresentation;
```

would you please help me to inpelement this

Thanks In advance

**Edit:**

```
Presentation *aPresentation = [app.presentationArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"Presentation is: %@ and it's Slide Count is: %d",aPresentation.pLabel, aPresentation.slides.count);

Slide *aSlide = [aPresentation.slides objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"Slide Label is: %@", aSlide.sLabel);

UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithString:aSlide.sLabel] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btn.frame = rect;
[btn setTag:i];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClick:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[imageView addSubview:btn];
```

**then The log is**

[788:c07] Presentation is: (null) and it's Slide Count is: 0
[788:c07] Slide Label is: (null)

Comment: You do it essentially the same way you'd do it in Java.

Comment: @HotLicks can you write your code in answer part please

Answer (score 2):

What happens when you do it this way:

```
Presentation *aPresentation = [app.presentationArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"Presentation is: %@ and it's Slide Count is: %d",aPresentation.pLabel, aPresentation.slides.count);

Slide *aSlide = [aPresentation.slides objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"Slide Label is: %@", aSlide.sLabel);

    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithString:aSlide.sLabel] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn.frame = rect;
    [btn setTag:i];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClick:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [imageView addSubview:btn];
```

Comment: first I had error with undeclared identifier app, that I added AppDelegate *app; in my header file but  , i have error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSPlaceholderString initWithString:]: nil argument'

Comment: [788:c07] Presentation is: (null) and it's Slide Count is: 0
[788:c07] Slide Label is: (null)

Comment: That means there is nothing in your `app.presentationArray`. There are no Presentations added to it.

Comment: :((( I really tierde do you know what would be problem, please help me

Comment: Come to iPhone/iPad room and let's continue discussion there.

Comment: I don't have access to that room :(

Comment: can you come in iOS Developer Family room I 'm not access any more to this iPhone/iPad  room

Answer (score 0):

Add a public method in your viewController, once your xml parsing is done call that public method it means, you are telling your viewController data is ready & update UI.

You can use appDelegate to inform viewController that data is ready, as appDelegate will be having instance of your viewController.

**EDIT:** You can have the following:

```
//in viewController.h
- (void) viewFillUp;

//in viewController.m
-(void)viewFillUp
{
      Slide *aSlide = [thePresentation.slides objectAtIndex:0];
      NSLog(@"Slide Label is: %@", aSlide.sLabel);

      UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
      [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithString:aSlide.sLabel] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      btn.frame = rect;
      [btn setTag:i];
      [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClick:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
      [imageView addSubview:btn];
}

//in appDelegate.h
 - (void) parsingDone;

//in appDelegate.m
- (void) parsingDone
{
    //suppose ur viewController instance is self.viewController
    [self.viewController viewFillUp]
}
```

Comment: but I allreday have   Presentation thePresentation; , would you please write the code you mean

Comment: where is ur startDidElement code written..? i mean in which class or viewController

Comment: would you please add it in your answer I need the code I'm new to objective-c

Comment: but you didn"t change my code, is the same, my problem is I don't know how should I add value to my object

Comment: what should I right instead of this  Slide *aSlide = [thePresentation.slides objectAtIndex:0]; or addinn to this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18064/discussion-between-vishy-and-antonmac)

Comment: wat is Presentation here.? is ur viewController?

Comment: am not able to get ur parsing steps & handling the parsed data.. can look at my sample app which shows how to parse xml data, handle data, & to display on table once parsing is done.. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/58723521/XMLParse.zip